# I just want to use splash script and return only job listing's urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm using scrapy and splash to scrape [this](http://www.gabteo.ro/jobs/) website, for some reasons I'm using splash and scrapy even though I know I can scrape its API. My problem is that I only want my lua script to return only job listing's `urls` rather than the whole `splash:html()` page, I've been trying to do that but I'm getting the error message below:-

```
 {
    "error": 400,
    "description": "Error happened while executing Lua script",
    "type": "ScriptError",
    "info": {
        "message": "Lua error: /app/splash/lua_modules/libs/treat.lua:45: cannot change a protected metatable",
        "type": "LUA_ERROR"
    }
}
```

The lua script I've been using is also shown below:-

```
function main(splash, args)
    assert(splash:go(args.url))
    splash:wait(5.0)
    local treat = require('treat')
    listings = assert(splash:select_all("ul.job_listings > li> a"))

    return {
       listing_urls = treat.as_array(listings)
    }

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function treat.as_array(tbl)
  -- the same function is available in
  -- Splash Python code as lua._mark_table_as_array
  if type(tbl) ~= 'table' or wraputils.is_wrapped(tbl) then
    error('as_array argument must be a table', 2)
  end
  setmetatable(tbl, {__metatable="array"})
  return tbl
end
```

`treat.as_array` tries to change the metatable of its argument.

The error is caused because `listings`'s metatable has the `__metatable` field set.

From https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-setmetatable

> If the original metatable has a __metatable field, raises an error.